# SU About page has 4 mods elected in 2011, the Election page shows 3

Tags: support, status-completed, election, moderator-elections

At the bottom of the [Super User About](https://superuser.com/about) page, it shows that four moderators were elected in the 2011 Community Moderator Elections ([Sathya](https://superuser.com/users/4377/sathya), [DMA57361](https://superuser.com/users/39366/dma57361), [nhinkle](https://superuser.com/users/20088/nhinkle), & [studiohack](https://superuser.com/users/6574/studiohack)).  However, on the [Community Moderator Election](https://superuser.com/election) page, it shows three users ([nhinkle](https://superuser.com/users/20088/nhinkle) is missing).

Can we make this consistent?

Comment: This is probably because at the time of the election, there were only 3 spots open, but then I got appointed a few months later when there was a new vacancy, and was chosen because I got 4th in the election. I agree that it's inconsistent, though I'm not sure how best to change it since there technically were only 3 elected at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have changed the elections results page to reflect this change - it will now show 3 spots open and 4 winners.